# Regex: two or more consecutive characters or character sequences

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace two or more consecutive characters or character sequences (as in, recurring consecutive patterns of characters) with a single instance of said character or character sequence. These can be any a-z characters. So that;

```
Foobar
Dummyy
Teststdata
```

becomes

```
Fobar
Dumy
Testdata
```

How do I do this? I'd normally post code on where I have managed to get to on my own, but in this case (and in regex in general), I am hopeless.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14166842/4772988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/(.+)\1+/g` => `$1` should do the trick

```js
s = "Foobar Dummyy Teststdata"

p = s.replace(/(.+)\1+/g, "$1")
document.write(p)
```

Do note, however, that this involves *lots* of backtracking, so use it with care.