# Remove two or more consecutive characters using stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to remove any time my script has 2 or more consecutive ticks. I know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166781/regex-to-match-two-or-more-consecutive-characters/14166842#14166842) that using regex you can detect any repeating characters with (.)\1, so I modified it to (`)\1 but that doesn't work. Why not?

`````
library(stringr)
example <- c("``", "````", "`")
str_replace_all(example, "(`)\1", "gone") #want the first 2 to say 'gone' and the 3rd to stay the same
`````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`````
library(stringr)
example <- c("``", "````", "`")

# THIS removes consecutives in pairs
str_replace_all(example, "(``)+", "gone") 

# THIS removes two or more consecutive
str_replace_all(example, "``+", "gone")
`````